# How to externalize API Manager Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to externalize API Manager Analytics without using Choreo Cloud?

In a situation where we don't have ELK stack, can we use custom log files, CSV or a Database to store Analytics information so we can run custom reports against them?

Can we write a custom handler to write Analytics information into a different external source?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager, by default uses logs files to log API Analytics information. It logs all the successful, fault and throttled event into the log file. With on-premises Analytics option, we can use ELK stack and with ELK stack approach, it uses Filebeats and Logstash to read those logs, and filter Analytics related information.

There is no out-of-the-box option to plug in a custom log file, CSV or a Database as the destination for Analytics information. However, we can write a custom handler/ event publisher (as demonstrated in [1]) to read those log files and collect Analytics related information and put them into a different format such as CSV, Database. Instead of publishing already available analytics events data, it is also possible to publish custom analytics data with the existing event schema as demonstrated here [2].

But this requires a lot of effort and sounds like implementing a new Analytics options from the scratch as this custom event publisher is responsible only for publishing the events and we will need some way of visualizing them.

As of now, there is only 2 options for API Manager Analytics and they are either Choreo Cloud (cloud) or ELK stack (on-premise).

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/samples/publishing-analytics-events-to-external-systems/

[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/samples/publishing-custom-analytics-data/